# Is there some congestion in the flag review queue?

Tags: support, flagging

I see 12 Flags "awaiting review", all 22 hours old.

I am in no hurry - I am concerned by the possibility that something might be broken.

Comment: we're busy people, things can take time. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is broken. Flags in the queue are sorted by weight not by time. So less important/weighted flags sink to the bottom of the queue.